# autocomplete search bar in angular js

Tags: css, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to make the `img` within my `div` responsive. I would also like the images to display as 3 in a row for maximum screen size.

**index.html**

```css
.container {
border: 1px solid #333;
border-radius: 8px;
background-color: #fff;
margin:5px;
padding:5px;
height:auto;
width:auto;    
}

img {
  max-height: auto;
  max-width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4"  ng-repeat="hbl in hbls"></div>
           <a href ng-repeat="h in hbl.data_list"><img ng-src="{{h.img}}" 
                 alt="" >
                  {{n.name}} </a>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Sanjika kumari you have unnesseccery `</div>`

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have unnecessary `</div>`
2. If you want `for maximum screen size` you have to set **`col-lg-4`** and **NOT** `col-sm-4` because `sm` is for smallest screen size and **not maximum**

```css
.container {
border: 1px solid #333;
border-radius: 8px;
background-color: #fff;
margin:5px;
padding:5px;
height:auto;
width:auto;    
}

img {
  max-height: auto;
  max-width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-4"  ng-repeat="hbl in hbls"></div>
           <a href ng-repeat="h in hbl.data_list">
           <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" 
                 alt="" >
                  Name</a>
</div>
```